# When i access a react-router route directly via url, it redirects to the '/' route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Whenever I access the `"/projects"` route via url, it redirects to `"/"`, but I can access it via a button for example.
I am 100% sure it's something wrong with the `AuthContext`, because if I just put `true` on the `condition` arg on `PrivateRoute` component, it works, but if the condition come from the `AuthContext`, it's buggy.

This is my `Router` component:

```
// private route, if condition is true, it render the children component,
// else, redirect to 'redirectRoute'
function PrivateRoute({ condition, redirectRoute = '/login' }) {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if(auth.loading) return null;

  return (
    condition
      ? <Outlet></Outlet>
      : <Navigate to={redirectRoute}></Navigate>
  )
}

function Router() {
  // this useAuth() is basically a useContext(AuthContext)
  const auth = useAuth();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          element={<PrivateRoute condition={auth.isLogged}></PrivateRoute>}
        >
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        </Route>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/projects"
          element={<PrivateRoute condition={auth.isLogged}></PrivateRoute>}
        >
          <Route
            exact
            path="/projects"
            element={<Projetos></Projetos>}
          ></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

And this is my AuthContext.js:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext({});

export function AuthProvider({children}) {
  const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this function send the jwt token to backend to verify
    // if its valid, if so, it do a setIsLogged(true)
    async function checkToken() {
      const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('costs_token'));
      if (!token) return false;
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        authorization: 'Bearer '+token
      }

      const response = await fetch('/auth/validatetoken', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        setIsLogged(true);
        return true;
      }
      localStorage.removeItem('costs_token');
      return false;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    checkToken().then(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{isLogged, loading}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I tried using a boolean value that do not come from `AuthContext`, it worked, but if the boolean come from the `AuthContext`, I can't access it directly via url, it redirects to `"/"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the app with an initially true `loading` state value so the `PrivateRoute` "waits" for the initial auth check to complete. When `loading` is initially false the `PrivateRoute` component fails the if-loading condition and conditionally renders the protected content or the redirect based on the passed `condition` prop. Since `auth.isLogged` is also initially false the `Navigate` component is rendered.

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // <-- initially true

  useEffect(() => {
    // this function send the jwt token to backend to verify if its valid,
    // if so, it do a setIsLogged(true)
    async function checkToken() {
      const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('costs_token'));
      if (!token) return false;
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        authorization: 'Bearer '+token
      }

      const response = await fetch('/auth/validatetoken', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        setIsLogged(true);
        return true;
      }
      localStorage.removeItem('costs_token');
      return false;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    checkToken().then(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{isLogged, loading}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
function PrivateRoute({ condition, redirectRoute = '/login' }) {
  const auth = useAuth();
  
  // Wait until auth status confirmed/loaded
  if (auth.loading) return null;

  return condition
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to={redirectRoute} replace />;
}
```